# std::set<Key, Comparator, Allocator>

Tags: c++, set, stdset

I've tried to use set to keep some configurations in a `trie` lately.

I've found a doubt on the comparator, for instance :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <set>

    using namespace std;

    struct Node{
      int position;
      int reference;
      Node(int r, int p){
        this->position = p;
        this->reference = r;
      }
    };

    struct Node_c{
      const bool operator()(const Node& n1, const Node& n2){
        // return n1.reference != n2.reference;
        // i've tried some functions here, like n1.reference != n2.reference ? true : n1.position < n2.position;  
      }
    };


    int main(){
      set<Node, Node_c> aNodes;

      aNodes.emplace(1,1);
      aNodes.emplace(1, 2); // i dont want to add this one, the reference already exists and the position is bigger than the last one
      aNodes.emplace(1, 0); // i want to replace the (1,1) for this one


      for(auto nd : aNodes){
        cout << nd.reference << ' ' << nd.position << '\n';
      }
    }
```

How could I keep the nodes with the lesser positions in order but excluding the equals references?

thanks.

Comment: Your compare function isn't correct; it's supposed to take a `std::less`-like functor, not an inequality metric. I'm not even sure how the set is supposed to order these values.

Comment: If you implement the functor to return if the value is less than the other, and `l < r` is false, and `r < l` is false, then the item already exists and won't be inserted. You can implement this in terms of position, since that's the value you seem to want.

Comment: I've tried some functions like this one i've added to the code (n1.reference != n2.reference ? true : n1.position < n2.position) ; I wonder whether it's supposed to do what i'm thinking  (if references are different or if the n1 position is lesser than n2 position)

Comment: No. You don't want to check for inequality. It's a `std::less`-like implementation. You need to check `a < b`, not `a != b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with a single method of `std::set`, because it strictly requires its elements to have unique keys!

`set.emplace` either inserts an element or it doesn't, but it won't replace an existing element, see [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/emplace)

The best solution for you would probably be either to use a `std::map<int, int>` where a `position` is mapped to `reference` and update the value if it becomes smaller, or keep using a `std::set` and write a custom method that first checks if the set contains an element and if yes, only replaces it if the new `reference` is smaller

Also, your comparator should compare for less-than (`<`), not for inequality (`!=`)

Comment: I really appreciated it, thanks a lot :)

I've thought about it recently, and I agree with you, thanks for this solution.

By the way, I've tried this following solution : 

```
  aNodes.emplace(1,1);
  auto it2 = aNodes.emplace(1,now);

  if(!it2.second){
    if(it2.first->position > now){
      it2.first->position = now;
    }
  }```

but yours seems to be better

Comment: I would actually say the set is the better approach: just you should use `auto it = set.find(item)`, and then `if (it != std.end() && it->reference > item.reference) { *it = item }` to replace the value in place, otherwise, add it. Don't use a map when you don't have to: the map has all the same issues, and none of the benefits.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I mostly agree with you, my initial thought was just that the current structure more or less resembles a mapping, whereas I normally consider elements in a set to be immutable.

Comment: @Tobias, fair and thumbs up. As long as the actual value you're ordering on is immutable though, in relation to the set, it will seem immutable.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Node {
    int position;
    int reference;

    Node(int r, int p)
            : position(p), reference(r) {
    }
};


struct NodeSet {
    struct AscendingReference {
        bool operator()(const Node &n1, const Node &n2) const {
            return n1.reference < n2.reference;
        }
    };

    struct SmallerPosition {
        bool operator()(const Node &n1, const Node &n2) const {
            return n1.position < n2.position;
        }
    };

    using Storage = std::set<Node, AscendingReference>;

    auto &propose(Node n) {
        auto ifind = storage_.find(n);
        if (ifind != std::end(storage_)) {
            if (not SmallerPosition()(n, *ifind))
                return *ifind;
            storage_.erase(ifind);
        }
        return *(storage_.insert(std::move(n)).first);
    }

    auto begin() const { return storage_.begin(); }

    auto end() const { return storage_.end(); }

private:
    Storage storage_;
};


int main() {
    NodeSet aNodes;

    aNodes.propose(Node(1, 1));
    aNodes.propose(Node(1, 2));
    aNodes.propose(Node(1, 0));

    for (auto nd : aNodes) {
        std::cout << nd.reference << ' ' << nd.position << '\n';
    }
}
```